# How to setup postgres application_name logging

Tags: postgresql, psql, application-name

I'm not much familiar with postgresql. I like to setup postgres application_name feature to log database changes (update/delete) in a history table.

I tried to find any help from online but couldn't find any article with basic steps. Could someone give me any kind of help.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a application_name is great idea. It has a two steps:

1. logging application name - set log_line_prefix in postgresql.conf

   ```
   log_line_prefix = '%a %u %d'
   ```
2. use application name - use SQL configuration statement or variable in connection string or environment variable

   ```
   SET application_name = 'myapp';
   ```

   or

   ```
   postgresql://other@localhost/otherdb?connect_timeout=10&application_name=myapp
   ```

   or

   ```
   PGAPPNAME=splunk psql -c "select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();" postgres
   ```

some documentation

- [related PostgreSQL doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING)
- [Overwriting a application name in psql (for psql based script identificati](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Overwriting_a_application_name_in_psql_.28for_psql_based_script_identification.29)